# javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jsp, servlets

DEFINED THIS IN JSP FILE:

```
    <sql:setDataSource      
     driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
     url="jdbc:microsoft.sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=GP"         
     user="sa" 
     password="sa123"
     var="dSource"/>   

    <sql:query dataSource="dSource" var="result">
         SELECT * FROM GP.FE_ENROLL_DATA 
    </sql:query>
```

**StackTrace:**

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource 
invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for dSource" at

org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql
              .QueryTagSupport.getConnection( QueryTagSupport.java:276) at

org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common
                    .sql.QueryTagSupport.doStartTag(QueryTagSupport.java:159) at
org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.sql.QueryTag.doStartTag(QueryTag.java:85) at
org.apache.jsp.enrollmentRecord_jsp
                ._jspx_meth_sql_005fquery_005f0(enrollmentRecord_jsp.java:477) at
org.apache.jsp.enrollmentRecord_jsp._jspService(enrollmentRecord_jsp.java:105) at
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) at
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) at
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432) at
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390) at
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334) at
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) at
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) at
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100) at
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953) at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) at
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) at
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041) at
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603) at
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310) at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Did you put sqldriver.jar at class path?

Comment: Yes. I have sqljdbc4.jar in WebContnt\WEB-INF\lib

Answer (score 1):

Your connection URL is

```
url="jdbc:microsoft.sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=GP"
```

As far as I can tell, your URL [should be either](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313100)

```
url="jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=GP"
```

for SQL Server 2000. Note the `:` instead of `.`. It can alternately have the form

```
jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]
```

[for SQL Server 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx).

Comment: I do not get error on defining <Sql:setDataSource...part. The error is happing when I include the <Sql:query part. The dataSource="dScource" is invalid

Comment: @OOP_LADY Your `DataSource` named `dSource` is built from the URL you specify in `sql:setDataSource`. You are registering a driver that doesn't map to the URL you want, which is why it says `no suitable driver`.

Comment: I tried  url="jdbc:sqlserver://sqlserver\sqlexpress://localhost:1433;databaseName=GP"  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                           Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for dSource"

Comment: @oop you'll have to figure out the appropriate URL for whichever database you are using.

Comment: Connection con = null;
String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/";
String db = "GP";
String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
String userName ="sa";
String password="sa123";
int sumcount = 0;
Statement st;                                                          try{
  Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
   con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+db,userName,password);
   String query = "SELECT * from FE_ENROLL_DATA";
 st = con.createStatement();
 ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);                while(rs.next()){System.out.println(rs.getString(1));}} catch(Exception e)

Comment: @OOP_LADY Yeah, you had to find the right driver and corresponding URL.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection URL is:

```
url="jdbc:microsoft.sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=GP"
```

Replace it with the following URL:

```
url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=GP"
```

or:

```
url="jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=GP"
```